# Ben Eater (youtuber) used an arduino expression that I can't find anywhere. What is it?

Tags: arduino

In the video [“Hello, world” from scratch on a 6502 — Part 1] by youtuber Ben Eater he shows a line of code 10 minutes 30 seconds into the video that uses an expressioin I simply can't find.

I've tried finding it in the arduino documentation website, tried searching it directly and I haven't found it on stackoverflow either... here is the code:

```
const char ADDR[]={22, 24, 26...} // these are pins in the Arduino Mega

void setup() {
    for (int n = 0; n < 16; n += 1) {
        pinMode(ADDR[n], INPUT);
    }
    Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop() {
    for (int n = 0; n < 16; n +=1) {
        int bit = digitalRead(ADDR[n]) ? 1 : 0;
        Serial.print(bit);
    }
    Serial.println();
}
```

In the line of code `int bit = digitalRead(ADDR[n]) ? 1 : 0;` is the expression I haven't seen anywhere else. It's supposed to mean *if digitalRead(ADDR[n]) is true then add a 1 if not add a 0 then asign it to the integer variable bit.* I haven't seen the `? True : False` expression anywhere else and I want to know where its reference is and where to use it and stuff like that. I don't even know what it's called!

Thank you if you answered! I'm still learning and I think tricks like these will help me immensely.

Comment: the ternary operator is at least 50 years old. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions in C++ are formed by combining operands and operators.

What the operators do can be found in the C++ reference.

This is the conditional or ternary operator. It is basically a short if else.

```
(expression 1) ? expression 2 : expression 3
```

If `expression 1` is `true`, `expression 2` is evaluated. If `expression 1` is `false`, `expression 3` is evaluated.

```
int bit = digitalRead(ADDR[n]) ? 1 : 0;
```

will assign `1` to `bit` if `digitalRead(ADDR[n])` returns `HIGH` and `0` else.

This expression doesn't make any sense though as `digitalRead` will return `1` or `0` anyway.

`int bit = digitalRead(ADDR[n]);` does the same

He is mistaken about digitalRead returning a boolean. It returns an integer.

https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/60f0d0b125e06dbf57b800192c80e5f60d681438/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c#L165

Even if digitalRead would return a boolean, false evaluates to 0 and true to 1 so storing that into an integer is absolutely no problem. It would implicitly be casted to integer and the value wouldn't change.